# How to mirror android screen/app to a screen programatically?

Tags: android, kotlin, casting

I am developing an android application and I'm trying to implement a button which initiates a screen mirror to a selected device.
I want it to be as straigth forward as possible, but the best i've been able to do is have it open the cast settings on the Settings app, which isn't a proper solution. It would be ideal to start screen mirroring with a single click.

Problem is i've tried using Googles Cast SDK but that only allows me to build custom HTML cast receivers, which isn't what I want, I just need a screen mirror from the android device to a screen/TV.
Is there any Android module/API that would allow me to do this with a single click, even if I have to use a Chromecast/Miracast device connected to the screen?

Answer (score 3):

No, sorry, this is not an option AFAIK.

At least part of this is privacy/security. You seem to want to be able to start screen mirroring purely from app code ("I'm trying to implement a button", "allow me to do this with a single click"). Your button is the "single click", and so you really want to be able to do this without user involvement at all (since there is nothing forcing that button to exist). Showing the contents of the screen on another screen that might be visible to lots of people is the sort of thing that users need to approve, which is why additional clicks will be required.

In addition, there may be more than one target for screen mirroring within range, and the user needs to be able to choose which one to use, if any.

Combine all that with limited support for wireless displays across the various Android device manufacturers, and there really isn't anything here for what you want.

Comment: I understand about the security and privacy concerns (even though this will be a very closed off aplication to a limited amount of people), but is there atleast anyway to have it so that the device selection screen is a custom popup on the app instead of it redirecting to the android Settings app?

Comment: "the device selection screen is a custom popup on the app" -- no. "instead of it redirecting to the android Settings app" -- FWIW, the Settings app may not be useful for all devices for setting up wireless display connections. There are tens of thousands of Android device models.